# What is the best way to create a map with mouse over?

Tags: javascript, html, flash, dictionary, graph

What is the best way to create a 2D plot, with different points in different coordinates (x/y coordinates) such that they are represented using different shapes on the plot, and whenever we click on one of them, or go with mouse over them, we see a text changing in a small window next to the plot?

If I could do this in HTML, that would be great.

If there is a generic Flash component that could do that, simply by loading some text data from URL, that would be IDEAL.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

```
<img src="planets.gif" width="145" height="126" alt="Planets" usemap="#planetmap" />

<map name="planetmap">
  <area shape="rect" coords="0,0,82,126" href="sun.htm" alt="Sun" />
  <area shape="circle" coords="90,58,3" href="mercur.htm" alt="Mercury" />
  <area shape="circle" coords="124,58,8" href="venus.htm" alt="Venus" />
</map>
```

Is this what you were asking?

Try this tut:

http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_map.asp

Good luck!

Comment: You would use the onmouseover event handler on each area element to set the contents of the box and onmouseout on the image to clear the contents of the box.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution I quickly put together using jQuery. It can easily be modified to use Vanilla Javascript, but for the sake of writing it quickly I've resorted to a framework.

It basically consists of a `<div>` that is relatively positioned, with **anchors** as **plots** that are **absolutely positioned**. This allows us to use coordinates to position the plots anywhere we like within the relative `<div>`.

You can create a few icons that will represent different plots on the graph and assign those to the *anchor* elements.

To make things nice and easy I've used a **JSON** object to store each ***plot*** so you can use it from a 3rd party source.

```
// change this to fit your needs
var plots = [
    {"width":30,"height":30, "top": 150, "left": 100, "content": "Lorem"},
    {"width":20,"height":20, "top": 100, "left": 20, "content": "Ipsum"},
    {"width":50,"height":50, "top": 20, "left": 20, "content": "Dolor"}
];

// store our 2 divs in variables
var $content = $("#content");
var $map= $("#map");

// Iterate through each plot
$.each(plots, function() {

    // store 'this' in a variable (mainly because we need to use it inside hover)
    var plot = this;

    // create a new anchor and set CSS properties to JSON values
    var $plot = $("<a />")
   .css({
        'width': plot.width,
        'height': plot.height,
        'top': plot.top,
        'left': plot.left
    })
    .hover(function() {
        // replace content of target div
        $content.html(plot.content);
    });

    // Add the plot to the placeholder
    $map.append($plot);
});
```

**I hope I've written it in an easy-to-understand way :)**

*Note that all of the above can be achieved using just HTML/CSS, just inspect the source to see what exactly gets created.*

**[Here's a demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ETZQT/)**